# For web, should a P3 image be converted to sRGB or left in P3?

Tags: color, website-design, color-spaces, monitor, web-standards

When preparing graphics for the web, if an image is using **Display P3** color space, should it be converted to the so common (and so unfortunately named) **sRGB EIC61966-2.1**, or left in its native Display P3?

Considering how common P3 displays are becoming, if P3 is likely to be the final viewing medium, I'm wondering if it's a disservice to images to "standardize" them by squeezing them into sRGB space and lose that fidelity.

[This article](https://creativepro.com/how-do-p3-displays-affect-your-workflow/) has really got me wondering.

[image: color space comparison 3d graph]

This question is concerned with web content primarily, but feel free to elaborate beyond the web.

Comment: If you dont convert them then they will be squezed regardless. You have no control over web color.

Comment: @joojaa Do you mean converting is a waste of time because browsers interpret them as sRGB anyway?

Comment: I feel this is the replay from "I'm using Retina and everyone will be using Retinas because it's superior so I will not desing for non retinas displays".

Comment: Well, first you might be more accurate and define which of the two separate color spaces that are called P3 you are refering to. Second P3 Displsy will maybe be a common colorspace in 10 years. DCI-P3 is pretty common in a cinema though. Second, your screen is most probably even showing P3 correctly since it hasnt been, or can not reach calibration to ambient. Anyway, color spaces dont work like you think. The image is an image its just data, the image does not know that the red it has is maximum P3 red. You can add a tag to image metadata saying it is supposed to be interpretted as some space

Comment: Now this tag may or may not be heeded. It can be stripped by compression, or the display system may ignore it. Now what would a monitor that can not reach P3 space do, it would either display it as if its own space was correct. Or it could use your tag and do one of four things, scale the image (essentially a sophisticated version of doing nothing), it could find the closest vibrant colors, it could clip. Or it could scale so that the space is otherwise intact. In either case you dont know whay the end result is as even having display reach sRGB is oit of reach to most internet users.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I don't see how you can draw any parallels between this and Retina. The Retina issue is solved easily - you prepare an image that's 2X the res of that specified in the CSS. People with Retina Displays appreciate it, and people without don't see a difference. Anyway, let's stay on topic, please.

Comment: You chose sRGB because if you dont then well... Erh no guarantees, no guarantees anyway. The internet just ignores you if you dont.

Comment: Thanks @joojaa - Of the two P3 color spaces you mentioned, one shows up in Photoshop as "Display", and the other one is what? "P3 Display"? What do I need to know about the differences? Also, of the four things a monitor would do with a tagged image, how do #1 and #4 scaling methods differ? I'm just curious. This is interesting to me.

Comment: Google rendering intent icc

Comment: @Mentalist The topic is that you should design for what is most common on the market and what would be the best for everyone without any processing. If you Want to use P3 use P3 with sRGB and show P3 only for people with P3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, everything destined for the web is best in sRGB. Sure that may change, but it won't next week, month or even year probably.

Why? Because most (if not all) displays are set to use sRGB by default from the factory and 95% of users don't know how to alter it and in all probability even if they do... don't care to alter it -- especially merely for *your* content.

sRGB is as close as you'll *ever* get to controlling color over the web.

P3 may show better color **to you** or perhaps better in Google browsers. But someone viewing the image in another web browser is going to be using sRGB - and different browsers will render differently. So, you are introducing a level of complexity to how the image displays, and therefore also introducing the possibly of poor color matching. sRGB has become, for the most part, universal.

Even **if** P3 becomes standard, it'll be *years* before it is as prevalent as sRGB. So unless you plan on creating images to be the same forever, you'll most likely be updating things prior to P3 becoming more standard. That article was written in March of this year.. it may be 2+ more years before operating systems and display manufacturers change, if they change.

For the record, the same conundrum was presented when Adobe RGB appeared on the scene... and years later, today, sRGB is still standard for content destined for the web for the same reasons I've outlined above.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to set up a Ps Action with a keyboard shortcut to convert a lot of images to sRGB. Thank you for answering.