# what is the best color profile for screenshot in macOS?

Tags: color-profile, mac, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot for a website(images in the website) in MacOS and use the image in other places/devices. what color profile should I use? I can use:

1. P3 color because my monitor is 99% P3 and it is widest?
2. sRGB color because most of monitor/phone screen has a 100% of sRGB?
3. use color profile that comes from Datacolor SpyderX Pro Color Calibration, because that is the most "accurate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sceenshot will have your display's profile.

After that, it's up to you what you wish to convert it to.
sRGB for maximum compatibility.
P3 for people with iPhones; & very little else..

Bearing in mind that iPhones' P3 is generally pretty accurate & sRGB is a 'best guess' that most people's computers will never actually be close to… it's a tough call.

I'd go sRGB.

*Late note:*
I always work with whatever profile my original image came with - if screenshot, then my display profile, if a photo then it arrives as Nikon's version of Adobe RGB. It stays at that until the very last minute, only at export do I reduce it to sRGB for web compatibility.
My Ps file always remains at its original profile.
This method only changes if I'm forced to - for instance if I'm layering material from different sources.

Comment: I am so ignorant. Imagine you have one computer with an external monitor. And you disconnect your monitor. Kaput. No monitor. You still can have a screenshot with Print-screen or whatever. Are you really having your display profile?

Comment: If you have no display, then you have no relevant profile. You might have the last one assigned, or you might get some generic or random default. It's not calibrated so it really doesn't matter. You have no calibrated input, so you have no calibrated output. All you have is 'guesswork'.

Comment: Could you please tell whether P3 screenshot will have a negative effect on devices that is only sRGB?

Comment: Very few people will ever see what you intended - yet 99% of people will never be even aware you intended something different. See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132100/for-web-should-a-p3-image-be-converted-to-srgb-or-left-in-p3

Answer (score 2):

A monitor's color profile is a localized thing, there is no such thing as a "best" color profile for a monitor.

A monitor should be correctly *calibrated* which will result in a **unique** color profile for *that* monitor.

Also be aware, you **can not** control the colors other's see on a web page. Some browsers are color managed, some aren't. Some users *will* calibrate their monitors, some won't.

When *saving* images for web use, often sRGB is a smart profile to embed because it's the most commonly used. However, even when using sRGB you **can't** guarantee *anyone* will else see the same colors you see. Trying to overly control color via the web is a lesson in frustration.